# Is there an operator or provision in RxJS to call every time a function is called?

Tags: system.reactive, rxjs

I have a function className.doSomething() which returns an observable.I want to know the time when this function was called or subscribed.

className.doSomething()
:callAtSubscribe( "print current time") 
:tap()
:subscribe()

Need something appropriate in place of callAtSubscribe.

Comment: I am not clear, you want to know when the `Observable` is subscribed to? Or when the method is called?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the method in an `Observable.Create`. This will allow you to track when the subscription is made. If you then wrapped that in a method, you could track when the method was called. This would allow you to see when the method was called (but potentially not subscribed to the result).

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var Rx = require('rx');

Rx.Observable.prototype.log = function (logger, sourceName) {
    var source = this;
    logger.debug({source : sourceName, kind : 'Created'});
    return Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
        logger.debug({source : sourceName, kind : 'Subscribe'});

        return source.subscribe(observer);
    });
};
```

This is a very cut down version of a *log* method I use. It can be heavily modified to include timings, wiretap of values, error, completions and terminations.

Comment: Obviously feel free to rename, but I think what you are actually looking for is a `log` method.